# Convert recursive tags into array with regular expression

Tags: php, regex

I have the following text

`hello <?tag?> world <?tag2?> xx <?/tag2?> hello <?/tag?> world`

And I need it converted into

array(
  'hello ',
  array(
    ' world ',
    array(
       ' xx '
    ),
    ' hello '
  ),
  ' world'
);

Tags are alpha-numeric, as long as they are closed with the matching tag, or `<?/?>`. Tags with same name may repeat, but wouldn't be inside each-other.

My question is which would be the most CPU-efficient way to go?

- use recursive preg_replace with callback
- use preg_match_all with PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE
- use preg_split to flattern all tags (PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY | PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE), into linear array then walk through and group tags.

If you can also provide the expression, I would be really happy.

Comment: You are describing a language that is not regular. That means regular expressions are not an appropriate solution.

Comment: Added rule that tags with same name can't be nested.

Comment: @webbiedave: *Theoretical* regular expressions are not appropriate, but most so-called regular expression implementations these days allow you to match non-regular languages as well.

Comment: Don’t worry, nested tags aren’t a problem with modern regexes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This turned out not so straightforward but hopefully this could be helpful to others. The biggest complication was returning non-string from callback function of preg_replace.

Thanks all who tried to help!

```
class Parser {
    public $ret=array();
    function loadTemplateFromString($str){
        $this->parsed_template=$this->tags=array();
        if(!$str){
            return;
        }
        var_dump($str);

        /* First expand self-closing tags <?$tag?> -> <?tag?><?/tag?> */
        $str=preg_replace('/<\?\$([\w]+)\?>/','<?\1?><?/\1?>',$str);

        /* Next fix short ending tag <?tag?>  <?/?> -> <?tag?>  <?/?> */
        $x=preg_replace_callback('/.*?<\?\/\?>/',function($x){
                return preg_replace('/(.*<\?([^\/][\w]+)\?>)(.*?)(<\?\/?\?>)/',
                   '\1\3<?/\2?>',$x[0]);
                },$str);

        /* Finally recursively build tag structure */
        $this->recursiveReplace($x);
    }
    function recursiveReplace($x){

        if(is_array($x)){
            // Called recursively
            $tmp2=$this->ret;$this->ret=array();
        }else{
            $x=array(4=>$x);
            $tmp2=null;
        }
        $y=preg_replace_callback('/(.*?)(<\?([^\/$][\w]+)\?>)(.*?)(<\?\/(\3)?\?>)(.*?)/',
            array($this,'recursiveReplace'),$x[4]);
        $this->ret[]=$y;
        if($tmp2===null)return;
        $tmp=$this->ret;
        $this->ret=$tmp2;

        $this->ret[]=$x[1];
        $this->ret[]=$tmp;
        return '';
    }
}
$p=new Parser();
$p->loadTemplateFromString('bla <?name?> name <?/name?> bla bla <?$surname?> bla '.
    '<?middle?> mm <?/?> blah <?outer?> you <?inner?> are <?/?> inside <?/outer?>'.
    ' bobobo');
var_dump($p->ret);
```

This outputs:

```
array
  0 => string 'bla ' (length=4)
  1 => 
    array
      0 => string ' name ' (length=6)
  2 => string ' bla bla ' (length=9)
  3 => 
    array
      0 => string '' (length=0)
  4 => string ' bla ' (length=5)
  5 => 
    array
      0 => string ' mm ' (length=4)
  6 => string ' blah ' (length=6)
  7 => 
    array
      0 => string ' you ' (length=5)
      1 => 
        array
          0 => string ' are ' (length=5)
      2 => string ' inside ' (length=8)
  8 => string ' bobobo' (length=7)
```

Comment: Well done! In `recursiveReplace(…)` I think you can omit the last group (`(.*?)`) for I think it will never be used, given it is at the end of the pattern but with a lazy quantifier.

Comment: ah, good point :) i added it as experiment and never removed.

Comment: Using this approach I improved performance 3 times over the previous implementation relying on substring matching.

Answer (score 0):

How about converting `<?tag`N`?>` to `<elem`N`>` and the parsing it as XML?

After you get a raw structure looking like the result you mentioned, you could/would verify it against your element structure (that is, ensure items are numerically inside each other etc).

Just add in a document element and you are set with this stylesheet:

---

**Edit:** After the fact that these tags are mixed with HTML came up, I thought I'd change my strategy. Please check out the following code first before a description:

```
$data = '<b>H</b>ello <?tag?> <b>W</b>orld <?/tag?>';

$conv1 = array(
//  original => entity
    '<?tag'  => '%START-BEGIN%',
    '<?/tag' => '%START-END%'
    '?>'     => '%END-END%'
);

$conv2 = array(
//  entity          => xml
    '%START-BEGIN%' => '<element',
    '%START-END%'   => '</element'
    '%END-END%'     => '>'
);

$data = str_replace(array_keys($conv1), array_values($conv1), data);

$data = htmlentities($data, ENT_QUOTES); // encode HTML characters

$data = str_replace(array_values($conv2), array_keys($conv2), data);

$xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>'.$data;

// You must apply the following function to each output text
// html_entity_decode($data,ENT_QUOTES);
```

Comment: Remaining text is HTML so that would be mixed up.

Comment: Thanks to @mousio for the suggestion.

Comment: Ow, I should have known it was for HTML :/ Simply encode `&`/`<`/`>`/… outside your own tags. If your own tags constitute a well-formed XML document (enclosed in a root element) then this can work, otherwise I would indeed refrain from using XSLT for HTML :]

Comment: Messing and encoding HTML would eat important CPU time and even after this we would still need to traverse the tree. Would that really be efficient?

Comment: @romaninsh - I agree perfectly, but I think this may be a lot more efficient than regular expressions. Whereas regex looks for a pattern (maybe multiple times), encoding is a one time pass - much more efficient than regex. If it were me, I'd do both and then profile them. Although regex unmistakably work miracles with patterns, they're undeniably slow compared to other solutions, so its always worth to try the alternative.

Comment: @Christian - I will consider this. I could assume that the document is proper html and convent tags into `<xml:tags>` then use xpath. Thanks for the tip.